ASP.NET MVC: stop controller open new tab went return Json
I'm encountering an issue with my controller. When I use <script> to call the controller, it returns a new JSON page instead of processing the response within the script.
My controller method looks like this:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == model.Username 
                                                        && u.Password == model.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            string generatedToken = TokenGenerator.GenerateRandomToken(_tokenLengthKey);
            DateTime tokenExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_tokenLifetimeMinutes);

            // Update user with new token and expiration
            user.Token = generatedToken;
            user.TokenExpiresAt = tokenExpiration;

            // Save Token and TokenExpiresAt to the database
            _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            Session["Username"] = user.Username;
            Session["Name"] = user.Name;

            // Redirect to home page
            return Json(new { success = false, redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, redirectUrl = Url.Action("Login", "Account") });
        }
    }

    return Json(new { error = "model is invalid" });
}

And my script calling this method looks like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    window.location.href = response.redirectUrl; 
                } else if (response.error) {
                    $('#errorMessage').text(response.error).removeClass('d-none');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error:", status, error);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

I want the JSON response to be processed within the script instead of displaying a new page.

Use your browser's JS debugger to inspect the response object and step-through your success: callback.

F12 in your browser, what is your response in the network tab?

You need to modify your function header. You don't need ActionResult as a response, but you need a JsonResult:
public JsonResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
  …

